# A phrase to describe the idea of 'high literature'?

Tags: phrase-requests

We have terms like **['high culture'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_culture)** and **['high art'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_culture#High_art)**. They are used to describe things deemed of a higher quality, or held in higher esteem, than products of popular culture.

We also have terms like *'art music'* and *'art film'.*
What I'm looking for is a similar term to describe literature.

Like *high literature* or *art book* or *art novel*, none of which I've heard being used.

For example, we can say:

> John wouldn't like *Transformers*. He only watches **art films.**

But what about:

> Harry wouldn't like Tom Clancy. He only reads ..... (what?)

Comment: It's usually called _The Canon_ in the trade, with capital letters one can hear loudly. The implication is that if you don't know what's in it, you don't know anything at all, rather like a revival preacher's view of _The Bible._

Comment: Consider the prevalence of terms like *popular culture, street art, pop music, family film*. That's because *culture, art, music, film* don't have anything like the same strong connotations to *superior or lasting artistic merit* that *literature* has "built-in" (though admittedly, not so strongly as *literary works*, but that's an obvious derivative). Consequently, most of us would tend to say ***high literature** is **tautological*** - and conversely, ***low literature** is **oxymoronic***.

Comment: Harry only reads *snooty* literature.

Comment: @HotLicks: You're only half-joking, right?

Comment: Only half.  Not nearly as funny as saying "literature" has "artistic merit" built-in, though.

Comment: @HotLicks: Yeah. That one was a riot!

Comment: 'Belles Lettres' is one (English) way of saying it.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - you have the answer - post it!

Comment: ... 'tall stories'?

Answer (score 7):

For some, it's

**literary fiction**

> Literary fiction is a term principally used for certain fictional
>   works that hold literary merit. In other words, they are works that
>   offer deliberate commentary on larger social issues, political issues,
>   or focus on the individual to explore some part of the human
>   condition. Literary fiction is deliberately written in dialogue with
>   existing works created with the above aims in mind. Literary fiction
>   is focused more on themes than on plot.
>
> Literary fiction is usually contrasted with paraliterary fiction
>   (e.g., popular, commercial, or genre fiction). This contrast between
>   these two subsets of fiction is highly controversial amongst critics
>   and scholars who study literature.
>
> [**Wikipedia**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literary_fiction)

Comment: I say broadly because 'fiction' excludes a lot of 'high literature' works.

Comment: The question is ambiguous - in the past "literature" referred to a broader range of writing than just fiction, e.g. essays, poetry, history, sermons, other serious works of non fiction. These days most of what's called literature is literary fiction, together with poetry and plays, although reading serious poetry or play scripts are much less common than fiction, so literary fiction is a good answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think this question has many easy answers in informal contexts.
By way of example,

> He doesn't read Tom Clancy: he only reads high-brow books.
>
> I disagreed with her about whether or not that novella qualified as serious literature.
>
> We love *Game of Thrones* but don't really think of the books as really deep literature.

All of these sentences are various levels of informal, and the last one is something which someone might say but would be unlikely to write.
They all also carry the desired meaning.

However, if you are writing in a formal context, I don't think there is a simple word or phrase that encapsulates this idea.

Depending on your needs, merely using the word "literature" may carry all of the connotations you desire.
It lends a bit more gravitas than "book", which is a bit pedestrian by comparison.
If you feel that the distinction is not sufficient, you might write "high-caliber literature".

Comment: I was also thinking of _literature_. You might need to put it in scare-quotes to emphasize this sense.

Answer (score 2):

Just *literature*, in contrast with *books* or *fiction*?

> Harry wouldn't like Tom Clancy. He only reads literature

Answer (score 0):

1. **Highbrow** ***literature / books / magazines / theatre etc.***
2. **Cerebral** ***literature / books***
3. **Sophisticated**  ***literature / works***
4. **Scholarly** ***works / editions***
5. **Erudite** ***works / researches*** *[erudite (adjective) - having or showing extensive scholarship; learned]*

Comment: Thanks for answering, but your examples are merely adjectives that could be applied anywhere. I'm looking for a phrase specific (at least partly) to literature.

Answer (score 0):

The aesthetic value of both literary and cinematographic works ranges from superficial entertainment to highly complex masterpieces, but the language has a special term *art films* for the films that are striving to be at the higher end of that scale, and no analogous term, such as *art literature*, for the comparable literary works. Why?

The answer is that the terms *film* and *literature* are **anchored** in the different parts of the scale of aesthetic merit. When one hears the terms *film* or *movies*, without any qualification, one is likely to think first of the typical products of the Hollywood studios. These are the films that are designed to be as commercially profitable as possible, by being entertaining and appealing to wide audiences, and that do not even attempt to achieve any artistic value that might get in the way of commercial success. Because this is the default for the concept of a film, we need a special term for the films that depart from the default, and *art film*, in some contexts, serves that purpose. On the other hand, the term *literature* is, for most people, anchored in the classics that they read as a part of their education. When they hear the word *literature* they first think of such works, which are of relatively high artistic value. We thus do not need any qualifier to add to *literature* in order to direct attention to the higher end of the scale of artistic merit, because the word *literature* does that by itself. In the case of literature, we do, however, need special terms, such as *pulp fiction* for the works at the lower end of the scale.

(This answer elaborates on what was first posted by FumbleFingers in a comment.)

Answer (score -1):

The  [classics](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Classical+Literature) may suggest the idea of high literature:

> - (Literary & Literary Critical Terms) the classics a body of literature regarded as great or lasting, esp that of ancient Greece or Rome. (Collins)
> - *A classic is a book accepted as being exemplary or noteworthy,* for example through an imprimatur such as being listed in a list of great books, or through a reader's own personal opinion. **Although the term is often associated with the Western canon, it can be applied to works of literature from all traditions, such as the Chinese classics or the Indian Vedas**. (Wikipedia)

- He only reads the classics.

Comment: Classics generally exclude recent books in their implication. What if he reads recent books, but like the Booker-award winning ones?

Comment: Also, classics can apply to movies and music as well. Still they have their own terms for this sense.

Answer (score -1):

You may use the term "classic literature". The term has an all pervasive appeal and can be used to any art form that has an aesthetic appeal and elevate us from the mundane.Let alone literature or fine arts any form of human excellence may be termed *classic.*

Comment: I don't think a book that was published in 2020 would be described as "classic literature". But there was a lot of literature published in 2020 of great artistic value.

Comment: To be classic one must not be dated.A classic innings by Tendulkar, a classic performance by Messi.You are right that we are prone to think in that fashion.

Comment: Call literature by any other name and use classic as an epithet. That would be fine

Comment: *Classic* has an implicit meaning of time-tested. So quite possibly, a 5- or 10-year old book can be described as classic, but one hot off the presses probably shouldn't be.

Answer (score -2):

> substantive literature

This is an appropriate adjective for art, film, and literature.  Moreover, it highlights Harry's reason; he may believe Tom Clancy books lack meaningful substance.

Comment: Really long books?